# Attributing code licensed under Creative Commons from Stack Overflow in Javadoc

Tags: java

The title is pretty clear. I have a code snippet I took from Stack Overflow that's licensed under Creative Commons and I want to attribute it properly.

My understanding is with Creative Commons you need to do TASL,

- Title (if present)
- Author (and preferably a link to their online presence)
- Source (where it is from)
- License (and preferably (or required?) a link)

Here is the doc comment. I have used the author field since it felt appropriate. I don't see it used often so it felt like a good place for attribution.

```
/**
 * This method overcomes the issue with the original {@link org.mockito.Mockito#spy(Object)} when
 * passing a lambda which fails with an error saying that the passed class is final.
 *
 * @author Originally <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/859314">Alex Objelean</a>'s
 * <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/54328868/1858327">code</a> licensed under <a
 * href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/">CC-BY-SA 4.0</a>
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <R, P extends R> P spyLambda(final Class<R> lambdaType, final P lambda) {
  return (P) mock(lambdaType, delegatesTo(lambda));
}
```

A "rendered" version is here.

> Author: Originally [Alex Objelean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/859314)'s [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54328868/1858327) licensed under [CC-BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)

As for what I'm looking to get out of this, I'd like to know if there's a standard or at least a common way of doing this. I'd like to know if using the author field is appropriate or not.

I'm not necessarily concerned about whether this meets the legal requirements of attribution required by CC-BY-SA. That's likely out of scope for this site. I'm mostly interested in people's thoughts on this style of attribution.

Comment: I suppose this is the last acceptable use for @author tag and kudos for trying to do the right thing. Unfortunately most of the question falls under the category "legal advice", which I am not qualified to address. I wonder if https://law.stackexchange.com/help would be suitable for that?

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen yeah I'll go there for the specifics but I'm still curious about the "formatting" here.